# from a variable detect the last occurrence of two letters (first letter is C and second letter can be A or B) and apply some delete and if condition

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

Consider below variable
letters="1234, MR45, MB46, 1234"
Need a command to detect last occurrence of M[B or R] where M is fixed and second letter can be B or R and delete everything before it
Expected output
output="MB46, 1234"
Also need if command to print error if letters variable doesnot have MB or MR word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Bash`** solution (regex matching):

```
letters="1234, MR45, MB46, 1234"

if [[ "$letters" =~ .*(M[BR].*) ]]; then 
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"   # MB46, 1234
else 
    echo "MB or MR word not found!"
fi
```

---

As a simplified shortened alternative the following GNU **`grep`** approach may be used:

```
grep -Po '.*\KM[BR].*' <<<"$letters" || echo "MB or MR word not found"
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine...in the command sed 's/.*\(M[BR].*\)/\1/' how to detect the last ocuurence of the word MB or MR from variable even if the letters are in lower case

Comment: there's no sed solution now. I've updated my solution to fit your additional condition *to print error if letters variable doesnot have MB or MR word*. If you need case-insensitive search - you should mention that in your question

Comment: A bash/sed solution: `sed -E 's/.*M([BR])/M\1/1' <<<"$letters"` maybe? (add an if to it).

Comment: Using `if [[ "$letters" =~ .*(M[BR].*) ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` seems better IMvhO.

Comment: @Arrow, as for `.*(M[BR].*)` - good hint, I've missed that. Thanks